# error: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, security

Good afternoon fellow developers I have a problem using BCrypt the error that occurs is that when I type username and password in postman the message below appears

```
Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

File using BCrypt

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{ 
    
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
        
    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("123");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select login, password, active_account from login where active_account=true and login=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from oauth_authorities where username=?")
            .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());           
    }
    
    //@Bean
    //public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    //  return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    //}
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

In the database the table has the following configuration

```
CREATE TABLE login
(
    login character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    senha character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    active_account boolean,
    CONSTRAINT login_pkey PRIMARY KEY (login)
)

CREATE TABLE oauth_authorities
(
    username character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    authority character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "username+authority_PKey" PRIMARY KEY (username, authority)
)
```

Data logged for testing when BCrypt is configured

```
Table login
login -> test
password -> $2a$10$sFKmbxbG4ryhwPNx/l3pgOJSt.fW1z6YcUnuE2X8APA/Z3NI/oSpq
active_account -> true

Table oauth_authorities
username -> test
authority -> user
```

When the above code is executed it displays the error Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

if I remove the BCrypt on the password it works normally as the code shown below

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{ 
    
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
        
    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("123");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select login, password, active_account from login where active_account=true and login=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from oauth_authorities where username=?")
            .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());           
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

In the database the table has the following configuration

```
CREATE TABLE login
(
    login character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    senha character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    active_account boolean,
    CONSTRAINT login_pkey PRIMARY KEY (login)
)

CREATE TABLE oauth_authorities
(
    username character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    authority character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "username+authority_PKey" PRIMARY KEY (username, authority)
)
```

Data logged for testing when not configured BCrypt

```
Table login
login -> test
password -> $2a$10$sFKmbxbG4ryhwPNx/l3pgOJSt.fW1z6YcUnuE2X8APA/Z3NI/oSpq
active_account -> true

Table oauth_authorities
username -> test
authority -> user
```

My file pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>backEnd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>backEnd</name>
    <description>Test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oauth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Where am I wrong if a colleague can help
Thanks

Comment: From where did you get the encrypted password used for testing?

Comment: Good morning joao, I created the passwords in several ways.
1 - Created online on BCrypt sites like https://bcrypt-generator.com/

2 - I've already built a code to generate them:
BCryptPasswordEncoder a = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String t = a.encode("test");

But in both cases I always get the same message

Answer (score 0):

I am finding the `configAuthentication` method weird since it is not part of the class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and is not called anywhere in your code (to my knowledge).
I would suggest you using the following one instead:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setUsername("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("123");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select login, password, active_account from login where active_account=true and login=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from oauth_authorities where username=?")
        .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());           
}
```

Comment: João, even putting this code, the error is the same.

I am using Tools Suite Version: 4.11.0.RELEASE

you may see an error in the pom configuration

Comment: Are you encoding your password when storing it? Additionally, you say "When the above code is executed it displays the error", what do you mean by "executed"? Is it when you try to log in or when you try to update a password for example?

Comment: When I say that the above code is executed, I mean that I pasted your code and restart the application. When I type username and password in postman it gives the same error "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt"

The password I copy and paste into the database.
Also already finished a test leaving the users in memory and the same error happens

Comment: Ok, but what are you doing in postman? Are you trying to log in or authenticate an API call? Can you add that test to the question? Thanks.

Comment: good morning joao, I put the compressed project on this link (.rar). I removed every part of the database this with authentication in memory and even so it keeps giving an error with BCrypt, if you want to take a look. There is also a folder with postman.
Let me ask you are you from Brazil. [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/87c2242c0cfdcd967ff18d7ec399c9f720210824125248/282fb6)

Comment: In the class `WebSecurityConfigAdapter` replace `BCryptPasswordEncoder create = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();` with `BCryptPasswordEncoder create = passwordEncoder();`. I am not sure what happens when you use multiple instances of `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

Comment: my friend i solved with this: @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderAutenticacao() {
        String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("pbkdf2", new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());

        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);

        return passwordEncoder;
    }

Comment: Well, if it works it works, but it seems too complex to me. I have a project working without all that and simply defining the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` bean.